# Im using this screen capture code to take a screenshot of the screen but sometimes it's returning null why?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ScreenShotDemo
{
    public class ScreenCapture
    {



        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct CURSORINFO
        {
            public Int32 cbSize;
            public Int32 flags;
            public IntPtr hCursor;
            public POINTAPI ptScreenPos;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct POINTAPI
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool GetCursorInfo(out CURSORINFO pci);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool DrawIcon(IntPtr hDC, int X, int Y, IntPtr hIcon);

        const Int32 CURSOR_SHOWING = 0x00000001;

        public static Bitmap CaptureScreen(bool CaptureMouse)
        {
            Bitmap result = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            try
            {
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
                {
                    g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

                    if (CaptureMouse)
                    {
                        CURSORINFO pci;
                        pci.cbSize = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CURSORINFO));

                        if (GetCursorInfo(out pci))
                        {
                            if (pci.flags == CURSOR_SHOWING)
                            {
                                DrawIcon(g.GetHdc(), pci.ptScreenPos.x, pci.ptScreenPos.y, pci.hCursor);
                                g.ReleaseHdc();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                result = null;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

I have 6gb memory ram on my pc so its never get to the null part.
But my brother have only 2gb memory and he get to the null part.

My program use this code to take a screenshot every 40ms with a timer in Form1:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
            using (bitmap = (Bitmap)ScreenCapture.CaptureScreen(true))            
            ffmp.PushFrame(bitmap);

            }  

        }
```

What can i do to solve this problem ? Why it happen ?

This is the ffmpeg class i have:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using DannyGeneral;

namespace ScreenVideoRecorder
{
    class Ffmpeg
    {
        NamedPipeServerStream p;
        String pipename = "mytestpipe";
        byte[] b;
        System.Diagnostics.Process process;
        string ffmpegFileName = "ffmpeg.exe";
        string workingDirectory;

        public Ffmpeg()
        {
            workingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);//System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);//Application.StartupPath; //Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);// +@"\workingDirectory";
            Logger.Write("workingDirectory: " + workingDirectory);
            if (!Directory.Exists(workingDirectory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(workingDirectory);
            }
            ffmpegFileName = Path.Combine(workingDirectory, ffmpegFileName);//@"\ffmpeg.exe";
            Logger.Write("FfmpegFilename: " + ffmpegFileName);
        }

        public void Start(string pathFileName, int BitmapRate)
        {
            try
            {
                string outPath = pathFileName;
                Logger.Write("Output Video File Directory: " + outPath);
                Logger.Write("Frame Rate: " + BitmapRate.ToString());
                p = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipename, PipeDirection.Out, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte);
                b = new byte[1920 * 1080 * 3]; // some buffer for the r g and b of pixels of an image of size 720p

                ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
                psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                psi.UseShellExecute = false;
                psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
                psi.FileName = ffmpegFileName;
                Logger.Write("psi.FileName: " + psi.FileName);
                psi.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
                Logger.Write("psi.WorkingDirectory: " + psi.WorkingDirectory);
                psi.Arguments = @"-f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr0 -video_size 1920x1080 -i \\.\pipe\mytestpipe -map 0 -c:v libx264 -r " + BitmapRate + " " + outPath;
                Logger.Write("ProcessStartInfo Arguments" + @"-f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr0 -video_size 1920x1080 -i \\.\pipe\mytestpipe -map 0 -c:v libx264 -r " + BitmapRate + " " + outPath);
                //psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process = Process.Start(psi);
                process.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
                p.WaitForConnection();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                Logger.Write("Exception Error: " + err.ToString());
            }
        }

        public void PushFrame(Bitmap bmp)
        {
            try
            {
                int length;
                // Lock the bitmap's bits.
                //bmp = new Bitmap(1920, 1080);
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
                //Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1280, 720);
                System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
                    bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                    bmp.PixelFormat);

                int absStride = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride);
                // Get the address of the first line.
                IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

                // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
                //length = 3 * bmp.Width * bmp.Height;
                length = absStride * bmpData.Height;
                byte[] rgbValues = new byte[length];

                //Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, length);
                int j = bmp.Height - 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Height; i++)
                {
                    IntPtr pointer = new IntPtr(bmpData.Scan0.ToInt32() + (bmpData.Stride * j));
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(pointer, rgbValues, absStride * (bmp.Height - i - 1), absStride);
                    j--;
                }
                p.Write(rgbValues, 0, length);
                bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
            }
            catch(Exception err)
            {
                Logger.Write("Error: " + err.ToString());
            }
```

Im taking a screenshot in Form1 each 40ms and push the bitmap to the Pipe in the ffmpeg class.
The ffmpeg.exe start as process once with arguments then its waiting for the connection.

When im looking on the task manager i see that the ffmpeg.exe start with 800-900mb memory and very fast jump to 1020 or more mb of memory.

How should i handle a case that the user like my brother have only 2gb of memory ? 
When he get out of memory the screen capture class return null to him and the program crash.

EDIT

I changed for the test the timer code:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            Image mScreenImage = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
            ffmp.PushFrame((Bitmap)mScreenImage);
            mScreenImage.Dispose();

        }
```

So now im taking one screenshot of the screen without a connection to the screen capture class and send this image each 40ms to the pipe.
And i see in the task manager that the ffmpeg.exe is over 1gb of memory .
So no wonder my brother have problems if he got only 2gb ram on his pc .

1. Why the ffmpeg.exe take so much memory ? Leak ?
2. How can i handle this ?

Comment: Im using ffmpeg.exe and for some reason the ffmpeg.exe take over 1gb of memory when i start the Process of the ffmpeg.exe

Comment: It looks like you're trying to record a video of the usage of your program. Piping raw bitmaps at 25 FPS to an encoder will ask a lot from the machine the program is running on. Do you want to write that part of your program yourself, or can you find a program that does only this part itself?

Comment: CodeCaster if someone could make this part of the program better it will be great. I want to do it my self i mean not using some examples but i dont mind if someone will take a look and fix my code in this part.

Comment: CodeCaster i edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know WHY an exception occurred, I suggest you handle whatever exception you find in your catch.

so instead of

```
catch 
{  
  result = null; 
}
```

try

```
catch (Exception ex) 
{
   // log the value of ex.ToString() to a file, the screen, something.
   System.IO.File.AppendAllText("debug.log",ex.ToString());
   result = null;
}
```

Comment: But i never get to the null part since i have 6gb ram . How can i simulate something that will take 6gb of ram so it will get to the null part ? My brother have 2gb ram so he get to the null part.

Comment: @joneK you could run it in x86 mode... that'll cut the available memory space down a bit

Comment: You can't. You'll have to capture the error on your friends machine.
I added a dirt-cheap way of writing errors to a file. Have your friend run the app, then examine the debug.log afterwards.

Comment: No i will send him a version with the log file .

Comment: The problem is not in the capture screen class with the null part. Its returning null from there but thats not the problem. The problem is that ffmpeg.exe take a lot of memory. I tried now to use in the timer each 40ms to send same image each time without using the screen capture class and the ffmpeg.exe was over 1gb of memory !

Comment: If you have a memory issue with ffmpeg specifically, then that's not something I can help with.

Comment: @joneK You can limit the amount of memory available to Windows to create low memory conditions: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/66482-memory-set-maximum-amount-used-windows-7-a.html